# Get Last Time for Each user with SQL Query

Tags: sql

I'm trying to get the last logon time from each user but, when I use MAX in the select statement the SQL query does not work it throws an error about Group By where if I dont use MAX the query returns the correct results. Here is an example of the date:

Usertable

```
Username        Date
--------        ------
user1           1/22/2017
user2           1/22/2017
user1           1/23/2017
user3           1/20/2017
user2           1/19/2017
user1           1/10/2017
user3           1/21/2017
```

UserInfo

```
   FullName         Dept    Username
   --------         ----    --------
   John Doe         IT      user1
   Jane Smith       HR      user2
   John Smith       IT      user3
```

Code

```
   SELECT UserTable.UserName, Usertable.Max(EndTime) as 'Date', UserInfo.Fullname 
   FROM UserTable 
   Left JOIN  UserInfo 
   On  UserTable.UserName = UserInfo.Fullname
```

Desired Result

```
   FullName         Username         Date
   --------         --------         ----
   John Doe         user1            1/23/2017
   Jane Smith       user2            1/22/2017
   John Smith       user3            1/21/2017
```

Comment: You should tag the question with the database you are using (although not really relevant in this case, that is a good practice on this site).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table alias is in the wrong place:

```
SELECT UserTable.UserName, MAX(Usertable.EndTime) as "Date", UserInfo.Fullname 
FROM UserTable LEFT JOIN
     UserInfo 
     ON UserTable.UserName = UserInfo.Fullname
GROUP BY UserTable.UserName;
```

The alias *qualifies* the column name, specifying what table it comes from.  The table has nothing to do with the `MAX()` function.  I also strongly discourage the use of single quotes for column aliases.  It is easy to confuse column names with string constants.

I would also suggest that you learn to use abbreviations for table aliases:

```
SELECT ut.UserName, MAX(ut.EndTime) as "Date", ui.Fullname 
FROM UserTable ut LEFT JOIN
     UserInfo ui
     ON ut.UserName = ui.Fullname
GROUP BY ut.UserName;
```

These make the query easier to write and to read.

Comment: If I use MAX(ut.Endtime) it throws an error   `Column 'ut.UserName' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`

Answer (score -1):

How about this

```
    SELECT UserTable.UserName, Usertable.Max(EndTime) as 'Date', UserInfo.Fullname 
       FROM UserTable 
       Left JOIN  UserInfo 
       On  UserTable.UserName = UserInfo.Fullname 
    GROUP BY UserTable.UserName, UserInfo.Fullname
```